# Fitting a broken html table inside a specific width with CSS

Tags: html, css, width, html-table

I have the following, broken, html that I can't really edit, nor preferably modify with javascript, and I'm trying to make it fit within x width: http://jsfiddle.net/P7A9m/2/

```
<div id="main">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                test
                test
                longWooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooord
                test
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

(I know that there's a mismatching amount of  but the problem would be the same if the first tr had 2 td.)

Now, I can't use "table-layout: fixed;" and set the table to the same width as the parent div because it'd make the content use only 50% of the available space.
Are there any ways to do what I want?

Comment: you can either use css `word-break: break-all;` (newer browsers only) or wrap it in a div with a width set and overflow hidden

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need the css property:

```
word-break: break-all;
```

Comment: Thanks, looks like I'll want to check out the word-break specs

I've used break-word instead of break-all btw, it's a little less aggressive :)

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
word-wrap:break-word;
```

This even works in IE6,

or

```
word-break: break-all;
```